# How to deploy rails 3 app using parallels Plesk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shared-hosting, plesk

How to deploy my Rails 3 app on shared hosting ?

When I buy hosting, they clearly mention Ruby on Rails support.

My hosting is Linux. The hosting service provider's technical member also don't know how to use Rails app. He is just saying that you can use Rails apps with FastCGI.

The hosting provider also does not allow to SSH access!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which host are you using? Some hosts have an area in the Cpanel where you can install ruby. Also if you aren't opposed to switching. I would suggest using webfaction for hosting ruby.

Comment: they provide Parallels's control panel  : http://www.parallels.com/

Comment: Is that a question or a statement? Also isn't parallels just software to run windows on mac? What do you mean by parallels control panel?

Comment: Okay nevermind. Are you talking about this? http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/ Is that what you are using?

Comment: Hmm... Well I have never used plesk before. But there appears to be some threads out there. http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?259881-Ruby-on-Rails-Integration-Installation-on-Plesk-10 or http://kb.parallels.com/en/5489

Comment: aha . super :). .thanks you solved my problem ..... million thanks :) :)

Comment: Great, I will post as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There appears to be some threads out there on this:**

- [forum.parallels.com/](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?259881-Ruby-on-Rails-Integration-Installation-on-Plesk-10)
- [kb.parallels.com/en/5489](http://kb.parallels.com/en/5489)

---

Resolution
As of version 8.1, Plesk Control Panel supports Ruby on Rails. There is not an option in the Plesk Control Panel that should be checked to enable Ruby on Rails support; you only need to install the ruby packages.

To install an application written in Ruby, take the following steps:

1. Go to Domains > your-domain.com > Setup.
2. Select the CGI and FastCGI check-boxes and click OK.
3. Connect to your FTP account, change to the `/htdocs directory`, and create a subdirectory where the application files will reside. Let's call this directory your_application, for illustration purposes.
4. Upload the application files to the `htdocs/your_application` directory.
5. Create a file with the name .htaccess in this directory, open it with a text editor of your choice, and add the following lines into the file:

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule ^$ /public/index.html [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/your_application/public
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/dispatch.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

1. Save the file.
2. Remove the `your_application/public/.htaccess` file.
3. Open the your_application/public/dispatch.fcgi file with a text editor and put the following lines there: `#!/usr/bin/ruby`
4. Save the file.
   The web application will now be accessible at the following URL: `http://your-domain.com/your_application`